# Python, have an error message i keep receiving

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my code:

```
def get_drink_price (drink):
    int 0.75 == "Coke" 
    if get_drink_price("Coke"):
        return Coke


# This is just to see what prints
print get_drink_price("Coke")
```

I keep getting this error message:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    int 0.75 == "Coke" 
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What's that?

Comment: That's... not Python.

Comment: Your code has *many different* problems; I fear there are too many faults here to even begin addressing them all. What stage are you at with your tutorial? It appears that you are following a tutorial for Python 2 as well (using a `print` statement instead of the `print()` function), but you tagged this with Python 3.

Comment: I cannot tell what you want to do exactly. Perhaps you should explain.

Comment: What is this supposed to do?

Comment: I think you should go through [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) before writing one more line of code. It will give you a minimal undestanding of the language. Unless you have a better explanation, it simply looks like you are trying to _brute force_ Python syntax into something that runs. Don't do that :)

Answer (score 5):

...because that isn't valid Python syntax. You have the following problems:

1. You should use `int(n)` to turn `n` into an integer. `int` on its own isn't valid (hence the `SyntaxError`) - you could define a variable called `int`, (e.g. `int = 1`) but that uses a single equals sign and should never be done, as you shadow the built-in `int()`;
2. `0.75 == "Coke"` is a boolean comparison, not any kind of assignment (and will *never* be `True`);
3. You keep recursively calling `get_drink_price` with no way to `return`; and
4. `Coke` is never defined, so `return Coke` would cause a `NameError` anyway.

It is completely unclear what you are trying to achieve with that function, but maybe:

```
def get_drink_price(drink):
    drinks = {'Coke': 0.75, 'Orange': 0.6} # dictionary maps drink to price
    return drinks[drink] # return appropriate price
```

Now

```
>>> get_drink_price("Coke")
0.75
```

Perhaps closer to what you were trying to do:

```
def get_drink_price(drink):
    Coke = 0.75 # define price for Coke
    if drink == "Coke": # test whether input was 'Coke'
        return Coke # return Coke price
```

but you should be able to see that the dictionary-based implementation is better.

Comment: Line at point 2. is completely wrong because of the `int` part, which looks like a bad attempt to _declare_ a variable in Python. Unless the OP meant something else, but I really can't tell.

Comment: Yeah, I wondered if that was supposed to be `Coke = 0.75` (neither of which is an `int`, but...)

Comment: re-+1 (you already had my +1) for extracting an acceptable hypothesis  from the OP's intentions. Another virtual +1 for not seeing your edit before the other answer :)

Comment: No worries, I was only a little affronted!

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that the code you are looking to create should be done something more like this:

```
def get_drink_price(drink):
    prices = { "Coke":0.75, "Pepsi":0.85}
    return prices[drink]


print get_drink_price("Coke")
```

The prices object in the function is just a dictionary, which is a standard python object.  You can look up more information about dictionaries here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries, but if what you're looking to do is find the price of a drink from its name, this is a simple, straightforward approach.